# cant throw Exception from inner try/catch loop LambdaExpresion Java

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, lambda

I have a list of table names called:

```
List<String> tables = Lists.newArrayList();
```

What I would like to do is create a single connection and only then delete all the tables, one by one.

My problem is that inside the `stmt.exceuteUpdate(sql)` line eclipse ask me to catch `SQLException`. But when I try to throw the same exception,
eclipse is saying: Unhandled exception type SQLException

In the method declaration I have:

```
throws  Exception, SQLException
```

Please help me. What could be the problem ?

```
try (Statement stmt = data.db.getConnection().createStatement()) {
tables.stream().forEach(tableName -> {
    String sql = "  DELETE  FROM " + tableName;
        int deletedRows = 0;
        try {
            deletedRows = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e; // eclipse says:  Unhandled exception type SQLException 
        }
});
```

I have tried catching both SQLException or Exception when using `throw e;`. But eclipse marks this as an Error!

If I will not use the `throw e;`, eclipse does not mark it as an error, but I do need to throw an exception there.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: `throw new RuntimeException(e);` if you just want the exception to go unchecked

Comment: It appears as if you do not need to use a lambda expression at all here. `for (String tableName : tables)` is exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lambda expression is used as a `java.util.function.Consumer` which cannot throw a checked exception from its `accept` method. Therefore simply throw a `RuntimeException`, e.g.

```
catch (Exception e) { 
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
}
```

Since this is pretty annoying you could also drop the stream approach and use a simple foreach loop.

Comment: This is of course broken for lambdas which execute on another thread.